# Only alphabetic entries in text box

Tags: validation, text, textbox, numeric

I need to validate the textbox in excel VBA of an userform which is supposed to contain names. I need to stop any type of numeric input. I tried Isnumeric function but it only works when the whole textbox contains only numbers. I need to find a code that will stop me from continuing if i input a data like this: "jack1". Any tips??

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
Private Sub TextBox1_KeyPress(ByVal KeyAscii As Form1.ReturnInteger) 
Select Case KeyNumbers
Case Asc("0") To Asc("99") 
Case Asc(".") 
If InStr(1, TextBox1.Text, ".") > 0 Then 
KeyNumbers = 0 
End If 
Case Else 
KeyNumbers = 0 
End Select 
End Sub
```

Comment: I tried it but it didn't seenm to work even after I changed the textbox's name to the name of my textbox. And i want to use it in a save button. So that if there is a number in anywhere in the cell the sub will be exited.